# (Non-repetitive division) formula for change of numerical representation of numbers in $\Bbb N$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I was thinking of a mathematical formula to calculate the $k$-th digit from a decimal number to a base $b$-number, that wasn't by doing repetitive division. I didn't find one in the internet, so I answered in the comments.

Comment: By "repetitive division", one might perform $k$ floored division by $b$, and then once more for the remainder. Now the intermediate remainders are ignored, so that can be collapsed to one division with one mod:

$$d'_k = \left\lfloor\frac{n}{b^k}\right\rfloor\bmod b$$

Comment: @peterwhy that's a better solution that mine. You should post it and I accept it as the valid answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "repetitive division", one might perform $k$ floored division by $b$, and then once more for the remainder. Now the intermediate remainders are ignored, so that can be collapsed to one division with one mod:

$$d'_k = \left\lfloor\frac{n}{b^k}\right\rfloor\bmod b$$

Answer (score 0):

First, I notice that , given a number $n_{10}$ with decimal representation (represented by the subscript), with the set of digits $\{d_0, d_1, \dots, d_K\}$ indexed by $k\in[0,K]$, where $k$ is the position in the decimal representation, and so:

$$n = \sum_{k}d_k\cdot 10^k$$

$n$ meaning the value and not the representation. Evaluating $n_{10}\mod 10$, we see that gives $d_0$, the far right digit if we read a number from left to right. If we took $n_{10}\mod 10^2$ then we get the value $d_0+d_1\cdot 10$. If we substrate the previous result and divide by $10$, the final result is the single digit $d_1$. If we generalize this result, then:

$${(n_{10}\mod 10^{k+1}-n_{10}\mod 10^{k})\over 10^k}=d_k $$

Now, changing to a new base of representation $b$ means to find the set $\{d'_0,\dots,d'_j\}$ such that:

$$n = \sum_{j}d'_j\cdot b^k $$

Finding $d'_j$ is just substitute $10$ by $b$:

$${(n_{10}\mod b^{k+1}-n_{10}\mod b^{k})\over b^k}=d'_j $$

Note that in the generalize formula, it use $n_{10}$ and not $n_b$ because how we represent values in $\Bbb N$, is by the base $10$. To change between different numerical representations, one must convert from a base $b_0$ to decimal, and then to base $b_1$, and that's it.

For example, if we want to calculate the third digit (position 2) from $5_{10}$ to $101_2$:

$${(5\mod 2^{2+1}-5\mod 2^{2})\over 2^2}={(5\mod 8-5\mod 4)\over 4}$$
$${{5-1}\over 4}=1 $$